# Mass updating many records in Rails with Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-activerecord

If I had to update 50,000 users, how would I go about it in a way that is best with a background processing library and not a N+1 issue?

I have users, membership, and points.

Memberships are related to total point values. If the membership is modified with point values  I have to run through all of the users to update their proper membership. This is what I need to queue so the server isn't hanging for 30+ minutes.

Right now I have in a controller action

```
def update_memberberships
  User.find_each do |user|
    user.update_membership_level! # looks for a Membership defined by x points and assigns it to user. Then Saves the user.
  end
end
```

This is a very expensive operation. How would I optimize for processing and in background so the post is near instantaneous from the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be after how to get this done with Resque or delayed_job. I'll give an example with delayed_job.

To create the job, add a method to app/models/user.rb:

```
def self.process_x_update
  User.where("z = 1").find_each(:batch_size => 5000) do |user|
    user.x = user.y + 3
    user.save
  end
end
handle_asynchronously :process_x_update
```

This will update all `User` records where z = 1, setting user.x = user.y + 3. This will complete this in batches of 5,000, so that performance is a bit more linear.

This will cause User.process_x_update to complete very quickly. To actually process the job, you should be running `rake jobs:work` in the background or start a cluster of daemons with `./script/delayed_job start`

One other thing: can you move this logic to one SQL statement? That way you could have one statement that's fast and atomic. You'd still want to do this in the background as it could take some time to process. You could do something like:

```
def process_x_update
  User.where("z = 1").update_all("x = y + 3")
end
handle_asynchronously :process_x_update
```

Comment: When I was playing with delayed_job I couldn't delay the .find_each part, only what's inside the block. And going through User.find_each was causing the app to hang for 10+ minutes before it could even add jobs to the queue.

I have to do something lke:     self.membership = Membership.find_by_points(self.points)

Comment: For delayed_job and resque, you need to put this code inside of a method on a model. Then you'll need to add `handle_asynchronously :your_method` after the method definition. Should I update my comment to show how to do this?

Comment: I'd love an example. I really appreciate it. Basically the meat is this:     self.membership = Membership.find_by_points(self.points)
    self.save for every User in db. And then just triggering that with one controller action without any immediate processing so request doesn't hang but every user will queue updating membership levels.

Comment: I ended up doing the following:     User.find_each do |user|
      UpdateMembershipLevelWorker.perform_async(user.id)
    end - nginx times out because it takes so long. Over 2 mins. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all). From the docs:

Updates all records with details given if they match a set of conditions supplied, limits and order can also be supplied.

It'll probably still take awhile on the SQL side, but you can at least do it with one statement. [Check out the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) to see usage examples.